# In what episode does a cat steal Zero's mask

Tags: code-geass

In what episode does a cat steal the zero mask, so that Lelouch has to chase it while he is being chased by all the girls from the school?

Comment: -1 - research effort - the answer can easily be found by looking up a list of Code Geass episodes, such as [the one from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Code_Geass_episodes) or by searching for `code geass cat mask`.

Comment: Your right, Im sorry for taking your time.

Answer (score 2):

Episode 6 (The Stolen Mask / 奪われた 仮面). The description is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Code_Geass:_Lelouch_of_the_Rebellion_episodes).